# Скрипт не работает в Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

Есть такой вот скрипт, который выводит картинки в случайном порядке:

```js
//параметры из url
function getUrlVars() {
  var vars = {};
  var parts = window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function(m,key,value) {
    vars[key] = value;
  });
  return vars;
}
$('#speed-p').val(getUrlVars()["speed"]); //параметры select
$('#speed-p-m').val(getUrlVars()["speed"]);//параметры select
//вывод изображений
$(function () {
  var current = 0,

      $imgs = jQuery('#exercise .cbk');
  imgAmount = $imgs.length;

  $($imgs.css('position', 'absolute').hide().get(0)).show();
  window.setInterval(swapImages, 1000);
  function swapImages() {

    var $currentImg = $('.cbk:visible');

    var $nextImg = $('.cbk:hidden').eq(Math.floor(Math.random() * $('.cbk:hidden').length));
    speed = 0;
    $currentImg.fadeOut(speed);
    $nextImg.fadeIn(speed);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="exercise">
  <div class="cbk">
    <img src="images/1.png" class="img-responsive" />
  </div>
  <div class="cbk img-responsive">
    <img src="images/2.png" class="img-responsive" />
  </div>
  <div class="cbk">
    <img src="images/3.png" class="img-responsive" />
  </div>
  <div class="cbk">
    <img src="images/4.png" class="img-responsive" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Проблема в том, что в Safari все работает отлично, но в Google Chrome на разных версиях — или вообще не запускается или запускается, но после перезагрузки страницы перестает работать (помогает только если заново зайти на страницу). Методом тыка пытался разобраться, но поскольку я новичок ничего не помогло. Прошу помощи коллективного разума.

Comment: В консоль ошибок никаких не пишет?

Comment: Консоль никаких ошибок не выдает. Самое странное, что в Chrome под Mac его еще можно запустить перезаходом на страницу, а в Chrome под Win7 вообще ни на что не реагирует. При этом в IE работает прекрасно, как и в Safari.

Comment: У меня в Хроме нормально все сробатывает : https://jsfiddle.net/asuLebde/

Comment: Подтверждаю, что срабатывает всё ок. Проверял на Mac OS, Ubuntu и Windows 10 в последних версиях браузера Chrome.

Comment: Попробуйте удалить кеш браузера - вдруг поможет... Может еще блокиратор в нем какой стоит как расширение? Или брекпоинт в консоле...

Comment: @AlexBub а теперь попробуйте открыть консоль перед открытием страницы, а не после того как все уже сломалось.

Comment: Заранее открытая консоль аналогично ничего не выдает.
https://jsfiddle.net/asuLebde/ -- по ссылке в хроме все отлично работает, какая-то мистика.
http://teme.com.ua/memory/letters/index.html?speed=5000 -- вот ссылка с этим же скриптом которая не работает в хроме. Возможно проблема может быть в чем-то еще?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всем спасибо за помощь! Похоже я где-то накосячил с CSS, изменив

```
$($imgs.css('position', 'absolute').hide().get(0)).show();
```

на

```
$($imgs.css('position', '**relative**').hide().get(0)).show();
```

Все заработало и в хроме :)